# I'm trying to encrypt a message for my homework assignment

Tags: c++

The gist of it is that every letter from `a`-`z` needs to be encrypted into a number.

For example `a` will turn to "1", `b` into "2" all the way to `z="26"`. Then I have to guess the number of possible outcomes for every encryption. For example 25114 can be 6 different thing. It can be BEAN,BEAAD,YAAD,YAN,YKD,BEKD.

My question is "How do I do this" ?
I've tried using `if` but it keeps printing "1" as an output every time.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a1,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z;

    cout<<"vnesi kod"<<endl;
    cin>>a1;
    if (a)
    {
        cout<<"1"<<endl;
    }
    else if (b)
    {
        cout<<"2"endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you mean `Encoded` probably.

Comment: The question can be translated as: _Given a string of `n` characters/numbers, in how many ways can I divide it into groups of 1 or 2 characters without any group representing a number larger than 26_

Comment: `int a1,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z;` doesn't seem to me to be the right way to go about this. Consider using a structure that maps letters to numbers (or if you can be guaranteed that the letters are contiguous and ordered in your character encoding, a bit of math).

Comment: To begin with you need to get the digits one by one or two by two from the number you input. And where do you initialize `a`? What do you think `if(a)` would do?

Comment: You can add spaces and commas. You can always write two digit numbers. You can write one ascii character. You can encode in various formats used to send binary data by email or http interfaces. The real question is, what have you tried?

Comment: @kvantour The OP says "I've tried using "if" but it keeps printing "1" as an output every time." which seems to indicate that this might be an actual attempt.

Comment: To the poster: Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please create a [mcve] of your actual attempt (if the code shown isn't it).

Comment: Hi OP, if the code shown *is* your actual attempt at solving this then I'm pretty sure that it would be best for you to try to find a tutor / a good book (booklist: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1116364) because it's - IMO - unlikely that this question can be edited into a form that's both useful for you and the community at large

Answer (score 2):

> Since this is a homework problem, I just give you some pseudo-code on how to solve this. You will still have to implement it yourself.

Let us assume you get a number as input existing out of *n* digits: *a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>3</sub> ... a<sub>n</sub>*

Since the alphabet contains 26 letters, we want to split this number into groups of 1 or 2 digits and if we have a group of two digits, you have to check if the number is smaller than 27. The quickest way to do this is to make use of a recursive function. It is not the cleanest, but the quickest. Let us assume the recursive function is called **`decode`**.

It is very easy to understand why a recursive function is needed. If we want to decode the number *25114*. There are two paths we need to take, groups of 1 and groups of 2:

- group of 1: translate the last digit *4* into "D", and **decode** the remaining number *2511*
- group of 2: check if the last two digits are smaller than 27, translate the last two digits *14* into *N* and **decode** the remaining number *251*

In pseudo-code this looks like this:

```
# function decode
#   input: the number n to decode
#          a postfix string p representing the decoded part
function decode(n, p) {
    # end condition: If the number is ZERO, I have decoded the full number
    #                only print and return
    if (n == 0) { print p; return }
    # group of 1: use integer division to extract the
    #             last digit as n%10 and
    #             remainder to decode is n/10
    decode(n/10, concat(translate(n%10),p) )
    # group of 2: use integer division to extract the
    #             last two digits as n%100 and
    #             remainder to decode is n/100
    # This does not need to run if n < 10 or if n%100 > 26
    if (n > 9 && n%100 <= 26) { decode(n/100, concat(translate(n%100),p) ) }
}
```

- The function `concat` concatenates two strings: `concat("AA","BB")` returns `"AABB"`
- The function `translate(n)` converts a number `n` into its corresponding alphabetic character. This can be written as [`sprintf("%c",64+n)`](http://www.asciitable.com/)

As is mentioned in the comments, this is not a very efficient method. This is because we do the same work over and over. If the input reads *25114*, we   will do the following steps in order:

```
step 1: translate(4), decode _2511_
  step 1.1: translate(1), decode _251_
     step 1.1.1: ...
  step 1.2: translate(11), decode _25_
     step 1.2.1: ...
step 2: translate(14), decode _251_
```

as you see, we have to decode *251* twice (in step 1.1 and step 2). This is very inefficient as we do everything more than ones.

To improve this, you can keep track of what you have done so far in a lookup table

Comment: I believe the OP only needs to find the number of possible ways to decode the string, not to print every possible decoded string. In that case you can write a linear-time dynamic programming solution instead of brute-forcing every possible decoding.

Comment: @bessiethecow you are correct. But since this is a homework problem I don't believe that dynamic programming is useful for him, unless he already has seen that. In the above, the solution is easily adaptable to get the count. Furthermore, I also mentioned that the presented pseudocode is quick and dirty, not necessarily elegant and efficient.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the ASCII table http://www.asciitable.com/ . I have had something like this similar for my homework as well. since 'a' = 97 and 'z' = 122, you could subtract the desired character from 96 to get the preferred value from the casted character.

For example:

```
int letterNum {(int)'a' - 97 + 1}; // 1

int letterNum {(int)'z' - 97 + 1}; // 26
```

Comment: If you're going to assume ASCII is used which isn't guaranteed, you can subtract `'a'`, instead of writing the encoding value. `c - 'a' + 1` is much more readable than `c - 97 + 1` and works for other encodings as long as the letters are consecutive.

Comment: I'd assume this is an intro class homework assignment to C++/OOP. And either way, it wasn't a solution, it was just an idea to help solve the problem.

Comment: Also, I made a couple mistakes on my interpretation. My bad